# Finding eigenvalues from equations questions

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am stuck on a question and not sure how to go about solving it. I tried forming a linear system but doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

Let B be a 4×4 matrix and {u<sub>1</sub>,u<sub>2</sub>,u<sub>3</sub>,u<sub>4</sub>} is a basis for R<sup>4</sup>.
Suppose
Bu<sub>1</sub> = 2u<sub>2</sub>, Bu<sub>2</sub> = 0, Bu<sub>3</sub> = <sub>u4</sub>, Bu<sub>4</sub> = u<sub>3</sub>.

Write down all the eigenvalues of B.

Comment: Write down the matrix for $B$ in terms of the basis $u_k$.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to notice is the Structure of a transformation Matrix.
Say we have a transformation Matrix A from the vector space V to the same vector space from the base B to the base B. Then the n-th column of the matrix would depict the image of the n.th base vector in B represented as a linear combination of the base Vectors in B (where the m-th row would correspond to the m-th base vector).

Going to back to your question with this information we can now construct the Matrix and determine the eigenvalues.
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now you may ask how I was able to construct this matrix. Note that the information $B \cdot u_1 = 2 \cdot u_2$ says that the image of the first basis vector is 2 times the second basis vector. This information helped constructing the first column of the matrix as follows (maybe try imagining turning the following equation 90° clockwise and aligning it with the first column of the matrix):
$$ 
 B \cdot u_1 = 0 \cdot u_1 + 2 \cdot u_2 + 0 \cdot u_3 + 0 \cdot u_4
$$
So every n-th column of the Matrix corresponds to the image of the n-th base vector and every row corresponds to a base vector and whether it's needed in the linear combination of the image of the base vector of the corresponding column.
With this matrix you should be able to compute the Eigenvalues (e.g. with the characteristic polynomial otherwise feel free to ask).

Hope this helped